# iPod Nano 7 Gen: use without Windows and MacOS

Tags: software-recommendation, unix, ipod-nano

I just got an iPod Nano 7gen ("iPod nano with Multi-Touch") for my birthday.

I have only one laptop and it's running Linux (Ubuntu 15.04 but may move on to Debian), is there any way I can sync music to the iPod?

Comment: What specifically do you want to do with the device and the laptop? What version of Linux and iOS are in play? If this is a software recommendation to replace iTunes - have a look at the [meta] site and search for [tag:software-recommendation] for advice on getting a good answer.

Comment: I just want to put music on my iPod. I'm running Ubuntu 15.04. Thanks for the links!